# Reset any identity column to start with 1 as next value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, identity

I'm building a SQL script to reset a database. To do this I want to empty several (not all) tables and reset their identity values to 0.

For some tables I use `TRUNCATE TABLE`, but this does not work when the table has is referenced by a foreign key constraint. For those tables I use `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableName, RESEED, 0)`. This works for most tables, but not for all. If a table never had any data, the current identity value is NULL instead of 0:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (Id int identity, Value varchar(10))
DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableName)

-- Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value 'NULL'.
```

If I use `DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableName, RESEED, 0)` on them, they will have 0 as next identity value. I can instead use 1 as reseed value, but then the tables which have had data in them will start on 2.

Is it possible to find the next identity value in any of the sys-views? If I just could get next value into a variable, I could use it to set next value to either 0 or 1. I've tried with `IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')` but it says 1 for both NULL and 0 as next value.

And please, I don't want any questions like "why do you need all of them to start from 1" or any other question suggesting another result than the one I'm asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use if all tables have identity field.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''?'', RESEED, 1)'
```

`MSforeachtable` is an undocumented, but extremely handy stored proc which executes a given command against all tables in your database.

To reseed ONLY tables with an identity column you can use the next script.
It also makes use of `sp_MSforeachtable` but taking into account the correct tables.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' 
    AND ''[''+ TABLE_SCHEMA + ''].['' + TABLE_NAME + '']'' = ''?'' 
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1) > 0 
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'', RESEED, 1)
END'
```

Use Following query to get Last Identity value inserted in tables in a database.

```
   SELECT TableName = OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) ,
       ColumnName = name ,
       OriginalSeed = seed_value ,
       Step = increment_value ,
       LastValue = last_value ,
       IsNotForReplication = is_not_for_replication
FROM sys.identity_columns
```

[Refer this for more details](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)

Comment: OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') does not give me the current identity value. It only tells if the table has identity or not.

Comment: @Palpie, the above mentioned query set the next identity value to 1 if table has identity field. this is done in recursion for all tables in database. If you have some other requirement then let me know.

Comment: IDENT_CURRENT() results in 1 when the current identity value is NULL. DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED, 0) behaves different when current identity value is null.

Comment: @Palpie, I hope the last query posted in the answer will do your job.

Comment: Seems to be just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I just used the second script to (temporarily) fix a problem I've had after a transactional replication to a second server. Run that post replication and everything's good to go!

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, do you basically want all future inserts to begin at `1`?

I'm no MS-SQL expert on this particular subject, but can you just truncate the table, then reset the identity as you've suggested, then if the identity is NULL, insert one record (which should get `0`) then delete it? Would that not leave the next record to be created be `1`?

Comment: Truncate dose not work for tables referenced by a foreign key constraint.

Comment: But yes, I want all future inserts to begin at 1.

Comment: And it shouldn't let you truncate in that case - if you have values in those foreign key columns, you'd be breaking integrity, and that's the whole point of the constraints.

Comment: I know. I didn't question why it is like that.

Comment: Inserting one record and then delete is one solution, but if I want to do this to any table I think it's easier to just delete the table and recreate it.

Comment: You can't do that if there are constraints either. I'm not sure why you mentioned FK constraints if they're not being used or causing a problem.

Comment: BTW, truncate doesn't let you truncate on a foreign constraint into the table even if the other table has no rows.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the constraint first:

```
ALTER TABLE foo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_foo_column
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE foo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

then do a truncate on the table